# Why in an empty debug.log opening when Windows 7 boots?

Tags: windows-7

My Windows 7 installation has begun opening a blank debug.log in Notepad every time it boots, but I do not know why or what process is causing this. How can I find out?

Comment: Did you change anything? Any updates or the like? Can you find out the path of that file?

Comment: It began happening a little while ago and I'm afraid I've no idea if anything had just changed. I assume the path is C:\Users\Trevor\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup as that's where it wants to Save-As.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I guess that this file already exists in the StartUp Folder. What happens is that Windows automatically tries to start files located here, in this case it simply uses the default program to open the file – in this case Notepad – which then pops up.

If this is the case, removing the file should suffice. You should also look which file might have created this, do you have some executable directly in that startup folder that might have created it? If that's the case you should move it to another place and simply add a shortcut to it to the StartUp Folder.